# Kernel continually crashes every day -- appears to try and re-boot itself while running

Tags: kernel, crash, 21.10

I am running Ubuntu 21.10 on Raspberry Pi 4 8GB system.  Every few days, the kernel is crashing.  It did it under 21.04 and I upgraded to try and fix the problem.  It didn't.

The only two main application damons running that I specifically installed: NUT UPS Network Tools, pihole and Docker.  Currently, no docker containers are running:

```
root@Raspberry-Ubuntu02:/var/log# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
13f798769cc7   mrlt8/wyze-bridge:latest   "python3 /app/wyze_b…"   7 weeks ago    Exited (137) 13 days ago             wyze-bridge
6eec7aa42d68   e160eddd0032               "/bin/sh -c 'unzip /…"   6 months ago   Exited (1) 6 months ago              competent_mccarthy
645f4e799cd1   a19f3e837571               "/bin/sh -c 'pip3 in…"   6 months ago   Exited (1) 6 months ago              sad_elion
1cee3c8068b4   a19f3e837571               "/bin/sh -c 'pip3 in…"   6 months ago   Exited (1) 6 months ago              gifted_pare
3eb5fd50e442   a19f3e837571               "/bin/sh -c 'pip3 in…"   6 months ago   Exited (1) 6 months ago              happy_payne
5b0c0e94094f   a19f3e837571               "/bin/sh -c 'pip3 in…"   6 months ago   Exited (1) 6 months ago              youthful_keller
780319f7d1e1   a19f3e837571               "/bin/sh -c 'pip3 in…"   6 months ago   Exited (1) 6 months ago              determined_knuth
d451a269c2f0   a19f3e837571               "/bin/sh -c 'pip3 in…"   6 months ago   Exited (1) 6 months ago              cranky_davinci
674180fe7399   a19f3e837571               "/bin/sh -c 'pip3 in…"   6 months ago   Exited (1) 6 months ago              vibrant_satoshi
5855e5fe36c7   a19f3e837571               "/bin/sh -c 'pip3 in…"   6 months ago   Exited (1) 6 months ago              distracted_curran
aa05bdac17b3   hello-world                "/hello"                 6 months ago   Exited (0) 6 months ago              zen_kalam
```

I've been trying to study the syslog file after every crash.  The only thing I find in common just before the crashes are these apps: tracker-miner, systemd-fsckd.service, NetworkManager-dispatcher.service.

```
Jan  1 19:33:10 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1098]: Stopped Tracker file system data miner.
Jan  1 19:33:10 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1098]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan  1 19:33:10 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1098]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan  1 19:33:10 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1098]: Failed to start Tracker file system data miner.
Jan  1 19:33:13 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan  1 19:33:19 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Deactivated successfully.

Jan  1 20:47:00 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd-resolved[671]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.


Dec 29 12:04:48 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1449]: Started Tracker file system data miner.
Dec 29 12:04:48 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1449]: Reached target Main User Target.
Dec 29 12:04:48 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1449]: Startup finished in 3.544s.
Dec 29 12:04:48 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[697]: <info>  [1640808288.6536] agent-manager: agent[2f80d7424bc11b49,:1.129/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/132]: agent registDec 29 12:04:50 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 wpa_supplicant[719]: wlan0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Dec 29 12:04:54 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Dec 29 12:04:58 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1449]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Dec 29 12:04:59 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Succeeded.

Dec 29 12:52:20 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd-timesyncd[667]: Initial synchronization to time server [2001:67c:1560:8003::c8]:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

Pretty sure I'm not running out of memory:

```
top - 20:55:14 up 9 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.08, 0.20, 0.18
Tasks: 271 total,   1 running, 270 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.1 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7759.6 total,   6163.8 free,    540.7 used,   1055.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   1024.0 total,   1024.0 free,      0.0 used.   6929.1 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                               
   2317 root      20   0   12616   3404   2824 R   1.3   0.0   0:00.76 top                                                                                                   
    702 root      20   0  334580  17308  14104 S   0.7   0.2   0:04.52 NetworkManager                                                                                        
    813 root      20   0 1409416  39852  25328 S   0.3   0.5   0:00.97 containerd                                                                                            
    826 nut       20   0    3712   1664   1236 S   0.3   0.0   0:00.12 usbhid-ups                                                                                            
   2166 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.16 kworker/1:3-events                                                                                    
      1 root      20   0  166200  11412   7060 S   0.0   0.1   0:04.37 systemd                                                                                               
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.02 kthreadd                                                                                              
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                            
      5 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.22 kworker/0:0-events                                                                                    
      8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                          
      9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_kthre                                                                                       
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_rude_                                                                                       
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_tasks_trace                                                                                       
     12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.42 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                           
     13 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.52 rcu_preempt                                                                                           
     14 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 migration/0                                                                                           
     15 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                         
     16 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.16 kworker/0:1-cgroup_destroy                                                                            
     17 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                               
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                                               
     19 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                                         
     20 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 migration/1                                                                                           
     21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.38 ksoftirqd/1
```

I don't even know where to begin to trouble-shoot this.  This is the last thing in /var/crash:

```
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie 4096 Dec 31 01:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root     4096 Dec 22 17:14 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root     whoopsie    0 Dec 31 01:58 _usr_bin_xfce4-session.0.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie   37 Dec 31 01:58 _usr_bin_xfce4-session.0.uploaded
```

And the contents of _usr_bin_xfce4-session.0.uploaded:

```
IW   _usr_bin_xfce4-session.0.uploaded                                                                                                                   Row 1    Col 37
```

27e45136-6a20-11ec-81f9-fa163e6cac46

How do I even begin to pinpoint how to resolve this?

**Update 1**

After more research (and more crashes), I believe I know what's causing the crash.  It appears that the kernel is attempting to re-boot itself while running:

```
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd-modules-load[306]: Failed to find module 'lp'
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd-modules-load[306]: Failed to find module 'ppdev'
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd-modules-load[306]: Failed to find module 'parport_pc'
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd-growfs[322]: Successfully resized "/" to 119.1G bytes.
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd083]
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.13.0-1011-raspi (buildd@bos02-arm64-026) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.37) #13-Ubuntu SMP PREE
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] random: fast init done
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
Jan  3 03:41:27 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
```

Why it is doing this, I still don't know.  Here are the Whoopsie events before the last crash:

```
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208541.3094] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:15:41] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:15:41] offline
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 dbus-daemon[707]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pi
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 dbus-daemon[707]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208541.4587] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:15:41] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:15:41] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208541.5086] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208541.5088] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:15:41] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan  3 03:15:41 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:15:41] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan  3 03:15:42 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:15:42] online
Jan  3 03:15:42 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 wpa_supplicant[730]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Jan  3 03:15:42 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208542.3692] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Jan  3 03:15:42 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208542.3694] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
Jan  3 03:15:51 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.

Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208861.3092] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:21:01] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:21:01] offline
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 dbus-daemon[707]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pi
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 dbus-daemon[707]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208861.4594] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208861.5048] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208861.5049] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:21:01] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:21:01] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:21:01] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:21:01] online
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:21:01] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jan  3 03:21:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:21:01] offline
Jan  3 03:21:02 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[936]: [03:21:02] online
Jan  3 03:21:02 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 wpa_supplicant[730]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Jan  3 03:21:02 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208862.3794] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Jan  3 03:21:02 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1641208862.3795] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
```

Anyone see anything there that I should look at to resolve this?

**Update 2**

I thought I would resolve this issue by simply re-installing Ubuntu.  I followed these instructions to install 21.10 on the unit, using a fresh new sd card: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-raspberry-pi-4#1-overview

Within less than 24 hours, the kernel crashed.  syslog reports the same as before, however I did notice some unusual entries:

```
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[2837]: <info>  [1641419425.4963] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 dbus-daemon[751]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatchJan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[1043]: [13:50:25] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[1043]: [13:50:25] offline
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 dbus-daemon[751]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[2837]: <info>  [1641419425.6392] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[1043]: [13:50:25] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[1043]: [13:50:25] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[1043]: [13:50:25] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[1043]: [13:50:25] online
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[1043]: [13:50:25] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[1043]: [13:50:25] offline
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[2837]: <info>  [1641419425.6951] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jan  5 13:50:25 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[2837]: <info>  [1641419425.6952] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Jan  5 13:50:26 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 whoopsie[1043]: [13:50:26] online
Jan  5 13:50:28 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 wpa_supplicant[787]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
Jan  5 13:50:28 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[2837]: <info>  [1641419428.2647] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Jan  5 13:50:28 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 NetworkManager[2837]: <info>  [1641419428.2649] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
Jan  5 13:50:35 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.




Jan  5 14:07:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27516]: (root) CMD (sar 1 30 > /home/ron/workarea/system/sar_cpu_1_min.txt)
Jan  5 14:07:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27515]: (root) CMD (sar -b 1 30 > /home/ron/workarea/system/sar_io_1_min.txt)
Jan  5 14:07:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27517]: (root) CMD (top -b -n 1 > /home/ron/workarea/system/top_1_min.txt)
Jan  5 14:07:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27521]: (root) CMD (sar -r 1 30 > /home/ron/workarea/system/sar_memory_1_min.txt)
Jan  5 14:08:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27534]: (root) CMD (sar -b 1 30 > /home/ron/workarea/system/sar_io_1_min.txt)
Jan  5 14:08:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27533]: (root) CMD (sar 1 30 > /home/ron/workarea/system/sar_cpu_1_min.txt)
Jan  5 14:08:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27535]: (root) CMD (top -b -n 1 > /home/ron/workarea/system/top_1_min.txt)
Jan  5 14:08:01 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27539]: (root) CMD (sar -r 1 30 > /home/ron/workarea/system/sar_memory_1_min.txt)
Jan  5 14:09:02 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27553]: (root) CMD (sar -b 1 30 > /home/ron/workarea/system/sar_io_1_min.txt)
Jan  5 14:09:02 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27554]: (root) CMD (sar 1 30 > /home/ron/workarea/system/sar_cpu_1_min.txt)
Jan  5 14:09:02 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27555]: (root) CMD (top -b -n 1 > /home/ron/workarea/system/top_1_min.txt)
Jan  5 14:09:02 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 CRON[27559]: (root) CMD (sar -r 1 30 > /home/ron/workarea/system/sar_memory_1_min.txt)
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Complete being skipped.
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd083]
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.13.0-1008-raspi (buildd@bos02-arm64-018) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-7ubuntu2) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU BinuJan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] random: fast init done
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x000000001a400000, size 320 MiB
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] Zone ranges:
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000003fffffff]
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000001ffffffff]
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000037ffffff]
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x00000000fbffffff]
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x00000001ffffffff]
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x00000001ffffffff]
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 2048000
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 3584 pages used for memmap
Jan  5 13:43:37 Raspberry-Ubuntu02 kernel: [    0.000000]   DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
```

So, I'm beginning to think this may be an issue with the Raspberry Pi 4 hardware itself.  Note how the log entries jump from 14:09 back to 13:43 as the system attempts to reboot itself.

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu on sd card or usb drive ?

Comment: Ubuntu installed on sd card.

Comment: @SomebodySysop I think I have a very similar issue: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/143763/raspberry-pi-periodically-breaks-my-access-point-all-devices-stop-getting-ip. Have you been able to solve this issue?